# On proving continuity for fractional exponential functions

Tags: continuity

I have a special problem here related to proving that a function is continuous.

We have:

$$f(x,y)=e^{\frac{x-1}{y}+\frac{y}{x-1}}\sqrt{1+\frac{x-y}{x+y}}$$

which shows that the function  does not exist at the line $y$ and not at the line $x=1$, nor on the plane $x=-y$.

How do I prove that this is nevertheless continuous on its domain?

The two factors are both containing forbidden regions, so how does one prove continuity for this hard nut?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean to say "the line $y=0$" and "the *line* $x=-y$."

Comment: Correct, yes the line y=0

Comment: The product of continuous function is continuous.  You also have to exclude points where the argument of the square root would be negative.

Comment: The negative arguments, indeed. Sorry I forgot about that. However, writing that the function is continuous on its domain after being defined as such, as there are no other points of inexistence, is it  sufficient as a proof?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  The exponential and square root are continuous wherever they're defined, so where both are defined, $f$ is the product of continuous functions, hence continuous.

Comment: Ok, that was clear! Thanks!

Comment: @saulpatz defining the points that yield negative argument in the root is quite tricky for this case. Can one sufficiently say that it is not existing where $-\frac{x-y}{x+y}>1$ ?

Comment: It isn't really very tricky.  Consider the cases $x+y>0$ and $x+y<0$ separately.  As to your question, it depends on what your teacher thinks, so I can't answer.